# How to receive/forward Event from/to another Component in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

i have a GUI which consists of a JTabbedPane.
I have three different JPanels A B C which are added to the JTabbedPane.
Every JPanel has a JComboBox and all of them are receiving their content from the same source (a txt-file).
Only in JPanel A there is the possibility to add/remove/edit the JComboBox content in this txt-file.
If i add/remove/edit the content of the JComboBox the other two JcomboBoxes in JPanel B and JPanel C have to be like refreshed to addopt the changes in the source.
The changes are performed in a ActionListener event fired by a Jbutton.

How can i forward these chnges in the txt-file which is the source of all JComboBxes to the other JPanels for the other two JComboxes to addopt the changes?

Answer (score 1):

> If i add/remove/edit the content of the JComboBox the other two JcomboBoxes in JPanel B and JPanel C have to be like refreshed to addopt the changes in the source.

The `ComboBoxModel` should be shared by all the combo boxes. Then when a change is made to the model it will affect all the combo boxes.

Basic code:

```
JComboBox comboBox1 = new JComboBox(...);
JComboBox comboBox2 = new JComboBox( comboBox1.getModel() );
```